# How do remove "Ignoring file in directory /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ as it has an invalid filename extension?

Tags: apt, 14.04, ppa, repository, do-release-upgrade

Since upgrading 13.10 to 14.04, I get these annoying messages each time I install, update, upgrade, and so on:

```
N: Ignoring file 'webupd8team-java-raring.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension 
N: Ignoring file 'bumblebee-stable-raring.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension 
N: Ignoring file 'steam.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'ubuntu-x-swat-x-updates-raring.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'xorg-edgers-ppa-raring.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'webupd8team-java-raring.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'bumblebee-stable-raring.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'steam.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'ubuntu-x-swat-x-updates-raring.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'xorg-edgers-ppa-raring.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

How do I fix the underlying problem told in the message?

edit: Sometimes, I get additional messages appended to the messages above:

```
W: GPG error: http://www.duinsoft.nl debs Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E18CE6625CB26B26
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/person/ppa/ubuntu/dists/karmic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/person/ppa/ubuntu/dists/karmic/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

And sometimes, I might others, but I cannot find the precise messages anymore.

Comment: Just rename `*disable` to `*disabled` and it will be silent.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To fix your first problem run this in a terminal:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.disable
```

(An older version of the package management tool left these files when you disabled the PPAs. Removing them is pretty safe)

Your second problem comes from and old Karmic repository. To find out which one run this in a terminal:

```
cd /etc/apt

grep -rw karmic *
```

Once you know which repository it comes from it would be easy to disable/remove it.

Comment: Moving .disable files to another location would be better than deleting.

Comment: I have the exact same problem as Flair, namely N: Ignoring file 'nginx.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension. But when I enter the command  sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.disable, I get the message: rm: cannot remove '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.disable': No such file or directory. Anything else I can try?

Comment: For all the newbies like me, I found the solution myself. Use command sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list.save.1 to get the specific file removed.

Comment: Just rename `*disable` to `*disabled` and it will be silent, no need to delete anything.

Answer (score 6):

[kubuntu 18.04]

I could not work out why the suffixes `.distUpgrade` and `.save` were ignored when there did not appear to be anything that explicitly sets this.

Then I discovered `apt-config dump | grep -i ignore` has entries for these and others:

```
Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently "";
Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: "~$";
Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: "\.disabled$";
Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: "\.bak$";
Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: "\.dpkg-[a-z]+$";
Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: "\.ucf-[a-z]+$";
Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: "\.save$";
Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: "\.orig$";
Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: "\.distUpgrade$";
```

I just renamed my dodgy one to be of of those extensions.  (I chose `.orig`)

Comment: This is very helpful, since it shows that `.disabled` is okay and `.disable` is not on the list!  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

maybe you should try  this command:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: \"(.save|.distupgrade)$\";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99ignoresave"
```

Comment: This would only mask the issue, maybe suggest a way to remove the files?

Comment: The dots should probably be escaped.

Comment: would this actually do anything as all the files that the op has listed are suffixed `.disabled` whereas the answer only has suffixes `.save` and `.distupgrade`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue in Ubuntu MATE 15.04. 
After

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list"
```

and

```
wget --quiet -O - http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

and

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I had this message:

```
N: Ignoring file 'pgdg.listwget' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

I solved this way:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.listwget /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was giving messages for *.save files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ directory. I removed them. Now only *.list files exist in there. And those warnings diminished.