# N: Ignoring file 'mariadb.list.old_1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

Tags: apt

How to fix this:

```
-N: Ignoring file 'mariadb.list.old_1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

Comment: It's just an informational message - you can configure apt to ignore it silently if you wish. See for example [How do remove "Ignoring file in directory /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ as it has an invalid filename extension?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458598/how-do-remove-ignoring-file-in-directory-etc-apt-sources-list-d-as-it-has-an)

Comment: Thx, and you say this ?

Comment: E: Unable to locate package php8.1
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.1'
E: Unable to locate package php8.1-common
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.1-common'
E: Unable to locate package php8.1-cli
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.1-cli'
E: Unable to locate package php8.1-gd
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.1-gd'
E: Unable to locate package php8.1-mysql
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.1-mysql'
E: Unable to locate package php8.1-mbstring
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.1-mbstring'
E: Unable to locate package php8.1-bcmath

Comment: That sounds like a separate question - please include your Ubuntu version and a description of what exactly you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Ma version de Ubunto et de 20.04 et j'aimerais connecter mon VPS à pterodactyl pour crée mon serveur minecraft